# i have a big problem with mysql and Xammp real_connect(): (HY000/2002)

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I was working perfectly my project on localhost, but I had to install openssl, and it was still working well, but today reboot my Mac, but when the xampp services start, first

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 203

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fed8/application/controllers/Login.php
Line: 8
Function: __construct

File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fed8/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Then try to enter localhost/phpmyadmin and error:

```
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

No se estableció la conexión: los parámetros están incorrectos.
 Índice de servidor inválido:
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
 La conexión para controluser, como está definida en su configuración, fracasó.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
 phpMyAdmin intentó conectarse con el servidor MySQL, y el servidor rechazó esta conexión. Deberá revisar el host, nombre de usuario y contraseña en config.inc.php y asegurarse que corresponden con la información provista por el administrador del servidor MySQL.
```

I already tried everything about the internet, in config.inc.php
-uncomment the host, I put 172.0.0.1, localhost:3008 and nothing
-change config to cookie
-I put a password
-I put the extra line in my.cnf

-reinstall xammp, update it to 8, it sends me errors in the controllers so I downgrade to 7.4.33

Comment: Is it from phpMyAdmin or CodeIgniter? Why have you tagged it with both?

Comment: it's happen using codeigniter, but the issue is phpyadmin

Comment: How can the issue be phpMyAdmin if it's happening in your own code? Do you realize that these are two completely separate applications?